# Move, resize and repeat

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

what I try to achieve is a succession of circles smaller in smaller from one position to another.

I first draw a big circle (right on the picture) and duplicate it, translate it to the left and resize it smaller, then I repeat the action manually. But I want it to be automatic. However in Illustrator if you use the "repeat" command (CTRL+D) only the last action is considered (resizing here).

Is there a way to automate that ? :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Doing this In Adobe Illustrator 
 
Make a Circle, Select it and go to <kbd>object menu - Transform - Transform each</kbd>

then you can move , scale, rotate or reflect your object and now with <kbd>CTR + D</kbd> command all things will be repeat which you had applied

For more details view this [Video](http://youtu.be/4tmq8aO42Lc)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a blend:

1. Draw your largest and your smallest circle;
2. Select both objects and choose the `Blend` tool (<kbd>W</kbd>);
3. Click an anchor in one of your objects (eg. the top anchor);
4. Click the corresponding anchor in the other object (the top);
5. <kbd>double click</kbd> the blend tool with the blend still selected;
6. Choose `Specified steps` and enter the number of intermediate steps you want;
7. <kbd>Object > Expand Appearance</kbd> as needed.

As long as you haven't expanded the result, you can still change the blend by editing the two terminal shapes, or the connecting path. The blend behaves as a group, so double-click it with the `Move` tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) to enter it and edit its parts.